# How to stop a FCM notification from getting displayed and making sound continuously?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to send my sensor values in the form of FCM notifications using ESP-8266 and Mobiz's "Firebase-ESP8266" Library. When the app is in background or killed, I am getting FCM notifications containing the specified message regularly. But the problem is that whenever a new notification comes it pops up/gets displayed on the screen and makes sound every time, which is quite annoying.

I want that once the first notification is received, then the upcoming notifications should not be displayed on the screen or make any sound until the user cancels it. I just want them to replace the existing notification in the notification tray.

I have been able to replace the existing notifications in the notification tray but the notifications are still popping up on the screen and making sound. Is there any solution to it?

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tokenapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
/>
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TokenApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_baseline_api_24"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/green"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/channelid"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_tag"
            android:value="MyTAG"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java class

```
package com.example.tokenapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static com.example.tokenapp.App.CHANNEL_ID;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    public static final String TAG = "MyTAG";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull  RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceiveCalled");
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceived:MessageReceived From: "+remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            long[] v={500,1000};
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_api_24)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setColor(Color.GREEN).setOnlyAlertOnce(true).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("")).setVibrate(v).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build();
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(1002,notification);
        }
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceived :Data:"+remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceiveCalled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull  String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceiveCalled");
    }
}
```

App.java class

```
package com.example.tokenapp;


import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Arduino code

```
#if defined(ESP32)
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseESP32.h>
#elif defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseESP8266.h>
#endif
const int analogInPin =A0;
int moistureValue = 0;
//Provide the token generation process info.
#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
//Provide the RTDB payload printing info and other helper functions.
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

/* 1. Define the WiFi credentials */
#define WIFI_SSID ""
#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""

#define API_KEY "API_KEY"

#define DATABASE_URL "tokenapp-ba3e5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com" 
#define FIREBASE_FCM_SERVER_KEY ""
#define FIREBASE_FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN_1 " "
//#define FIREBASE_FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN_2 "ANOTHER_RECIPIENT_DEVICE_TOKEN"
#define USER_EMAIL "USER_EMAIL"
#define USER_PASSWORD "USER_PASSWORD"

FirebaseData fbdo;
//int counterHigh =0, counterLow =0;
void sendLowMessage();
void sendHighMessage();
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

unsigned long sendDataPrevMillis = 0;

void setup()
{

    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    pinMode(D1,OUTPUT);

    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(300);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();

    Serial.printf("Firebase Client v%s\n\n", FIREBASE_CLIENT_VERSION);
 
    Firebase.begin(DATABASE_URL, "");

    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);

     fbdo.fcm.begin(FIREBASE_FCM_SERVER_KEY);

    fbdo.fcm.addDeviceToken(FIREBASE_FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN_1);

   // fbdo.fcm.addDeviceToken(FIREBASE_FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN_2);

    fbdo.fcm.setPriority("low");
    fbdo.fcm.setTimeToLive(1000);

     if (!Firebase.beginStream(fbdo, "/PUMP_STATUS"))
        Serial.printf("stream begin error, %s\n\n", fbdo.errorReason().c_str());
        fbdo.setBSSLBufferSize(512, 2048);
}
void loop()
{
  moistureValue= analogRead(analogInPin);
  Serial.println("Moisture Reading = ");
  Serial.print(moistureValue);
  if (Firebase.ready() && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > 5000 || sendDataPrevMillis == 0))
    {
        sendDataPrevMillis = millis();
             
        Firebase.setIntAsync(fbdo, "/MOISTURE_READ", moistureValue);
        
        
    }
    if(moistureValue<300 )
    {
      
        sendLowMessage(); 
      
        
     
      }

      if(moistureValue>550 )
      {

       
           sendHighMessage();
                 
      }


     if (Firebase.ready())
    {

        if (!Firebase.readStream(fbdo))
            Serial.printf("sream read error, %s\n\n", fbdo.errorReason().c_str());

        if (fbdo.streamTimeout())
            Serial.println("stream timeout, resuming...\n");

        if (fbdo.streamAvailable())
        {
          
                          if(fbdo.stringData()== "ON"){
                           digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
                          }
                          else{
                            digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
                          }
        }
    }  
}  




void sendHighMessage()
{
      fbdo.fcm.setCollapseKey("MyKey");
     fbdo.fcm.addCustomNotifyMessage("tag","MoistureNotification");
   
    fbdo.fcm.setNotifyMessage("Heya User", "The value of moisture in the soil is " + String(moistureValue) + "\n Please Switch ON the water pump");

    //fbdo.fcm.setDataMessage("{\"myData\":" + String(moistureValue) + "}");

    //Firebase.broadcastMessage(fbdo)
    //Firebase.sendTopic(fbdo)
    Serial.printf("Send message... %s\n", Firebase.sendMessage(fbdo, 0) ? "ok" : fbdo.errorReason().c_str());
   
    if (fbdo.httpCode() == FIREBASE_ERROR_HTTP_CODE_OK)
        Serial.println(fbdo.fcm.getSendResult());
        
    Serial.println();
    

}

void sendLowMessage()
{

      fbdo.fcm.setCollapseKey("MyKey");
     fbdo.fcm.addCustomNotifyMessage("tag","MoistureNotification");
    fbdo.fcm.setNotifyMessage("Heya User", "The value of moisture in the soil is " + String(moistureValue) + "\n Please Switch OFF the water pump");

    //fbdo.fcm.setDataMessage("{\"myData\":" + String(moistureValue) + "}");

    //Firebase.broadcastMessage(fbdo)
    //Firebase.sendTopic(fbdo)
    Serial.printf("Send message... %s\n", Firebase.sendMessage(fbdo, 0) ? "ok" : fbdo.errorReason().c_str());
       if (fbdo.httpCode() == FIREBASE_ERROR_HTTP_CODE_OK)
        Serial.println(fbdo.fcm.getSendResult());
        
    Serial.println();
}
```

In my MainActivity.java class, I am just retrieving my device token nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, notificationNumber, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Please try to implement this way from below link may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487811/4042384