# Push notification is not showing on notification bar

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have implemented the firebase push notification by following a YouTube video and its working fine when app is in the background but when the app goes on the foreground it will not show the notification but I can see the notification coming in the logcat.

here is the code-

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        getFirebaseMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    public void getFirebaseMessage(String title, String msg){
        Log.d("abc", title);
        Log.d("abc", msg);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "plasmatechannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(101 , builder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from API level 26, all notifications must be assigned to a channel to set the behavior that is applied to all notifications in that channel.

Please try to implement the below way in your existing code

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                    try{
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(Constant.CHANNEL_ID);

                        NotificationChannel channelnews = new NotificationChannel(Constant.CHANNEL_ID, "Breaking News", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                        channelnews.enableLights(true);
                        channelnews.setShowBadge(false);
                        channelnews.enableVibration(true);
                        channelnews.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
                        channelnews.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100});
                        channelnews.setSound(url,new AudioAttributes.Builder().build());
                        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constant.CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channelnews);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx,"")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (notificationBuilder == null) {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx,"")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }

            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            notificationBuilder.setSubText(subtext);

            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationNumber, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Please read detail from
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel

hope it may help you

Comment: yes the problem was with the channel id , I read the documentation and found my solution

Answer (score 0):

That's how the Firebase Push Notification works. It will show notification when your app is in the background. When it is in the foreground, only `onMessageReceive` is called and you have to perform some action (maybe changing the UI) to notify the user because they are using your app.

Comment: I have done the implementation in "onMessageReceive" to build the notification please check the code I have uploaded.

Comment: The code you provided does not relate to the problem you mentioned in the title. Please edit it too